# What kind of personal data is available for iOS developer?

Tags: ios, privacy

I'm going to use some application both on my iPad and iPhone (both devices on iOS 6.0.1). The data that I will operate in the applications are synchronized through the cloud owned by application developer.

Potentially, the developer can tie my personal data with the data that he puts into the cloud.

Q: What personal information about the owner of the device an application developer can obtain using documented and undocumented features of the iOS SDK?

For example:
- Apple id
- Phone number
- Card number
- Email
- First Name / Last Name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can get is an identifier of the device. You can get the telephone number, but then your app would be rejected. So in short, all you can do is ask the user for his personal data (or to choose his contact from the address book) - no automatic way to get these.

All you can get is less personal things like IP address of the device, device type etc.

Comment: Can developer get my personal data through undocumented features?

Comment: What do you mean by undocumented? On a jailbroken device? Yes. In an app you downloaded from the app store? No.